# In C# result looks successful, but data not inserted in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

am scratching my head from couple of days, not being able to find what I did wrong. I have a database "compinfo.sdf" and table "cname" in local database.Dataset as "compinfoDataset".I am using this code to insert the data.

```
static class sqlFunction
{
  static public void insert(String _compName)
  {
    static private SqlCeConnection connection =
        new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\compinfo.sdf");
     try
     {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT into [cname]  VALUES (@companyName)", connection);
        commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", _compName);
        int result = commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
    catch (SqlCeException exception)
    {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

From another class I am sending data as :

```
sqlfunction.insert(companyName);
```

So when this code is executed, I get the result of execution as 1 (in message box). But when I check the data in database table, its again nothing there. Please help me find the error.

Comment: `.sdf` is SQL Server compact edition, not MySQL?

Comment: Are you rebuilding the solution each time? Because if `compinfo.sdf` is set to `Copy to output directory` the file will be overwritten each time you build. Exact same problem as user instances with `.mdf` files. Try inspecting the `sdf` in `bin\Debug\...`

Comment: Yes. this is what the problem looks like. But even when Its with "copy" option, shouldnt I be able to see the data in the data source or server explorer ??

Comment: Which database are you checking after insert operation? And how do you check it? Make sure to check the one in `bin\Debug\ ` folder. If you are checking from Server Explorer in Visual Studio, then check if it is connected to the database in `bin\Debug\ ` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely Visual Studio is set to always copy the `sdf` file to the bin directory, overwriting any previous changes. Change the behavior to "Do not copy", as explained [in this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx).